# Child objects not rotating with parent object

Tags: modeling, animation, edit-mode, keyframes, parent

I made some flower petals and I want them to rotate in a circle around my sphere so I parented them to an empty and tried rotating it 360 degrees but my child objects (the petals) arent rotating at all with it when parented.

[image]

File:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the options, deactivate *Transform > Affect Only Parents*:

[image]

Comment: I think you misspelled, shouldn't he deactivate it? Sorry, don't know if i should inform you or edit.

Comment: yes you're right thanks  ;)